# cannot require files with dynamic path anymore

Tags: angular, webpack-2, angular2-cli

We used to be able to to do this :

```
    let path = 'test.component.ts';
    let file = require('./path/to/file/'+path);
    console.log('file',file);
```

But this is not working any more with the latest cli.

This works :

```
    let file = require('./path/to/file/test.component.ts');
    console.log('file',file);
```

So basically , webpack wont let me require file dynamically anymore in cli .

Comment: you should change it with     var path = ''

Comment: @SaeedPy What ?

Comment: change {let} with {var}

Comment: are you using `AOT` ?

Comment: @AnkitSingh , no I'm not , but does it matter?

Comment: yes, AFAIK AoT allows only static values for now, which means `require('./path/to/file/'+path);` can't be resolved because `path` makes it dynamic. I had this issue with dynamic variables in `template` ie `<h1>${someVar}</h1>`

Comment: @AnkitSingh , I've been looking into their code and I realised they've created a buggy loader which does all this hacks , I'm not using AOT now, but even if I do , I should work.

Comment: yeah, I hvn't used `ng cli` much, maybe loader is at fault. is there any error btw ?

Comment: Isn't ng cli using AOT for their production builds now? Also dynamic requires doesn't make it easy for tree-shaking, so it should be considered a good thing that this doesn't work also in dev mode.